# why is a comment in blade used in view cache and breaks the app

Tags: php, laravel, symfony, caching

i figured out why my application breaks. i just asking myself why.

i have a comment in my blade template like:

```
// @foreach($array as $single_array => $single_value)
//     @if($single_value['hours'])
//         Array[{{$single_array}}] = true;
//     @else
//         Array[{{$single_array}}] = false;
//     @endif
// @endforeach
```

my app brings an error and in laravel log there is a error with:

```
[2017-05-18 13:33:35] local.ERROR: ErrorException: Undefined variable: $array in /dir/dir/storage/framework/views/6d55dbc26cff4b472bc2fe463d746c694d87d562.php:83
```

why is the comment interpreted and wants to be used in my programm? its commented in my cached view too so it shouldnt make a diffrence or?

i have cleared my cache and the symfony cache, the browser cache and everything but only **delete** those commented lines works. after this everythng runs fine.

Comment: http://laravel-recipes.com/recipes/86/using-comments-in-blade-templates

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default the blade templates don't have the php opening tag. So any code inside is the same as html. When comment code to you is actually not commented in the blade file and would require the variables in the code. The proper way to comment this in blade would be like so.

```
{{--@foreach($array as $single_array => $single_value)--}}
    {{--@if($single_value['hours'])--}}
        {{--Array[{{$single_array}}] = true;--}}
    {{--@else--}}
        {{--Array[{{$single_array}}] = false;--}}
    {{--@endif--}}
{{--@endforeach--}}

OR

{{--@foreach($array as $single_array => $single_value)
    @if($single_value['hours'])
        Array[{{$single_array}}] = true;
    @else
        Array[{{$single_array}}] = false;
    @endif
@endforeach--}}
```

Comment: this works but my editor doesnt even recognize that this is a comment. thank you

Comment: It's laravel blade exclusive syntax. As far as i know, only phpstorm supports it out of the box for now.

Comment: guess my company has to upgrade me on phpstorm ;)

Comment: Which editor or ide do you use? there are many os plugins to give support to blade syntax for popular ones.

Comment: atm vsc. but i installed 2 syntax highlighter, still no visible comment.

Comment: @Gabbax0r https://atom.io/packages/language-blade https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=onecentlin.laravel-blade